# VSCode Shortcut based on filename

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to create a shortcut that pastes something based on the filename?

For example, I have a file called `featured-brands.js`, now I want to create a shortcut that inserts `featured-brands` in my code when I'm working inside of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a [snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) now:

```
"Filename Namespace": {
    "prefix": "namespace",
    "body": [
        "${TM_FILENAME_BASE}"
    ],
    "description": "Namespace for file"
},
```